# Can names of abilities or spells within a game be trademarked/copyright?

Tags: game-design, legal, copyright, licensing, trademark

Okay, say I want to create an RPG similar to and takes inspiration from such games as Final Fantasy, The Elder Scrolls, Shin Megami Tensei, Pokemon, etc. and I would like to use familiar names in some cases because the names simply fit from a design perspective (like from anything as mundane-but-aptly-named as "Water" or "Waterfall" to something like "Ultima" or "Souleater"). For the sake of the question I want to make it clear I'm not attempting a parody or the sort (it's going to be its own franchise), just most ability/spell names I can think of tend to come from video games or board games I've played.

Comment: Ask a lawyer....

Comment: Many things can be copyrighted in some countries, few things can be copyrighted in all countries. That's why many games end up launching with different titles in different countries - they usually change the title in only one country if they face a lawsuit in that country.